# Spring Boot, HikariCP and JDBCAuhthentication

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, hikaricp

I'm trying to setup basic authentication based on a MYSQL database through Spring Boot, HikariCP as a datasource and JDBCAuhthentication but I think there's something I don't quite grasp.

Here is the relevant code :

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

<!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<!-- Persistence dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


<!-- Tools dependencies --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lostdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = lostuser
spring.datasource.password = lostuser


## Hibernate Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Show SQL queries
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

# Hikari CP
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1200000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
```

**My Web Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()  
            //Permit these requests without authentication
            .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/signup").permitAll()
            //Any other request must be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuthentication")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}


@Autowired
public void configureGloal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {         
     auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
     usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username=?").
     authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from authorities where username=?");;
 }

}
```

**The login page**

```
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/navbar.html"></div>        
    <div class="container">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${param.error}">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success" th:if="${param.logout}">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <br>
            <form th:action="@{/userAuthentication}" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group"><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"/> </label></div>
                <div class="form-group"><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"/> </label></div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary"/></div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/navbar.html"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <br>
        <h4>
        Logged user: <span sec:authentication="name"></span>
        <br><br>            
        </h4>

        <p>
        <a href='${/admin}'>Admin access</a>

        </p>

        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="POST">
            <div><input type="submit" value="Log Out" class="btn btn-primary"/></div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Database creation script :**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `lostdb`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `lostdb`;
use `lostdb`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `authorities`;

CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  UNIQUE KEY `authorities_idx_1` (`username`,`authority`),
  CONSTRAINT `authorities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES 
 `users` (`username`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE, `authorities` WRITE;

Some "INSERT INTO" to have some data in there...
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Connexion to the database may be working as I don't get any error in the console (beside a "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt" warning in the console and if I mistype a table name in the query from the WebSecurityConfig class, I get a message saying it doesn't exist) but I am never redirected to the home page with the username displayed in the greeting message. A login attempt will result into the login's page "Invalid username and password" error message and if I do to go the index page manually, I get an "anonymousUser" value for the "name" parameter.

There's something that I don't get in how the framework compares the values from the databases to the data entered by the user and how the user is supposed to be retrieved as an entity.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: It sounds like the passwords are stored incorrectly in your `users` table, that is: they don't seem to be hashed with bcrypt. How did you populate that table?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I inserted them manually for now. I tried to use an online bcrypt-generator tool (https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator) to generate bcrypt passwords (with a now char(68) password entry in the sql script)  preceded by the "{bcrypt}" tag but I still get the message...